# Making a bracha for someone else, can then use for one's self?

Tags: halacha, blessing, kiddush, motzi-yedei-chovato

Consider the following 2 situations:

Reuvan is unable to make kiddush and has asked Shimon (who already made kiddush for himself) to make kiddush for him (Reuvan). 
Shimon, however, says he can't drink the wine. Reuvan therefore is hearing Kiddush from Shimon then drink the wine. After this is done, Shimon decides that he does want to have some wine as well. May Shimon drink without a bracha and rely on the bracha he had originally made for Reuvan in order to be motzei him in Kiddush (assuming he hasn't interrupted with speaking, etc.)? The question is, since he had only Reuvan and not himself in mind, would the bracha help for his own drinking?

Similarly the same question could be asked in regards to other brachos (that are made on a mitzvah.) For example putting on tallis or tefillin, hanging a mezuzah, etc. (all assuming there is no hefsek in the middle, etc.). If Reuvan couldn't make the bracha himself but Shimon could and did in fact make the bracha on the mitzvah but had in mind that it should only be done for Reuvan, can he then do the mitzvah and rely on that bracha?

Comment: See Mishna Brurah 167:92.

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly, it does not work.

The Rema writes in O.C. 209:2:

> ואם היו אחרים שותים גם כן ויין לפניהם ודעתו גם כן על יין שהיה סבור שבכוסו יין ובירך בורא פרי הגפן ונמצא אחר כך שבכוסו מים או שכר כשחוזר ושותה אחר כך יין אין צריך לחזור ולברך ויוצא בברכה שבירך על כוסו אף על פי שהיתה בטעות דהא דעתו היה לשתות גם כן שאר יין גם הוציא האחרים ששותין שם ולכן ברכתו ברכה
>
> If others were drinking wine, and you planned to drink wine and thought you had wine in your cup, and you made a boreh pri hagafen, and then discover that you have water or beer in your cup, when you subsequently drink wine you do not need to make a new blessing, and you are exempted with the blessing which you made, **since your intention was to drink other wine [also]** and you also exempted the others with your blessing

The Mishna Berura there extends the case to even where you did not explicitly have intention to drink other wine, you just had "stam da'as." But when you had specific intention to *not* drink wine, it would not work.  Intention to have some of what you are making the blessing on, either explicit or implicit, is necessary.